# How to let an object not take up its natural width

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a DOM object aligned vertically. One of them, say `<div id="foo">`, has a natural width wider than the rest. I want that element to not take up its natural width but let the other parts (the widest among its siblings, or the parent width, whichever wider) determine the width, and let the horizontal overflow part of `<div id="foo">` be hidden.

```
<div>
  <div>some content</div>
  <div id="foo">a content with very wide width</div>
  ...
  <div>some content</div>
</div>
```

I would want it to look like this:

[image]

where the div with content `"Another content"` determines the width because its natural width is wider than other siblings excluding `<div id="foo">`.

How can I do that using CSS?

Comment: foo should always be as wide as it's parent unless you have either set a width on it or made it inline.  If it is being stretched because of non breaking elements then just add `overflow:hidden` to it to hide it's overflow

Comment: could you give a demo of what the result should look like, using static widths? I can not really follow what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may use display table properties and negative margin to reduce virtually width of elements to nothing . **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/Emyqp)**
HTML test

```
<div class="content">
  <div> blab bla bla bla bla </div>
  <div class="refW">my width</div>
  <div>blop blop blop blop blop blop blop blop blop</div>
</div>
```

CSS test

```
.content {
  display:table;
  width:0%;/* will expand to fit to content */
  margin: auto;
  overflow:hidden;
  border:solid;
}
.content div {
  white-space:nowrap ;  
  margin-right:-9999px;
  background:red;

}
.content div.refW {
  margin-right:0px;
  background:green;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked with the CSS for `div` and `.refW` reversed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the content of the child divs take up the width of its parent div you need to add the overflow:hidden property to the parent div. In this way the child will take the with of its parent even if its width is greater than the parent.

[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zinnia_dev/33Aeq/)

Code snippet:

**CSS Class**

```
#foo {
    width:500px;
}
.parent {
    width:400px;
    height:auto;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
    <div>some content some contentsome contentsome contentsome contentsome contentsome contentsome contentsome contentsome contentsome contentsome contentsome contentsome contentsome contentsome contentsome content</div>
    <div id="foo">a content with very wide width a content with very wide widtha content with very wide widtha content with very wide widtha content with very wide widtha content with very wide widtha content with very wide widtha content with very wide widtha content with very wide widtha content with very wide width</div>
    <div>some content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @sawa: You can have a look now at the demo fiddle

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to have understoon you request, but:

try to set a width to the wrapper of all elements

```
<div style="width: xxxx; overflow:hidden;">
  ...
  ...
  ...
  ...
</div>
```

then set a 100% width to the wider object inside you wrapper (in this way, you can fit its width to the wrapper's width)

```
<div>
  <div>some content</div>
  <div id="foo">a content with very wide width</div>
  ...
  <div>some content</div>
</div>



<style>
  #foo {
     max-width:100%;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: I get it correctly what I want, but I want to do that without explicitly setting a width to the wrapper.

Comment: @sawa well, you can set a width of "100%" to the wrapper :) (this is a responsive solution for all your problems)

Comment: That would make the wrapper be as wide as the first of its ancestors with explicit width. I want the wrapper width be determined by the width of the widest element except for `<div id="foo">`.